# Get H2 text and href values from inside all H2 tags on the page using xpath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I know nothing, ZERO, about xpath or DOM.

In the end I need the href value and the content of the span from 12 H2 tags on the page. I have figured out how to get each item individually but getting them all in one shot isn't clicking, no matter how much I read. A little help?

```
<h2 class="make-it-pretty">
    <a class="more-pretty" href="some-file-somewhere">
        <span class="another-class">Product Name</span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

Here is what I use to get them individually.

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $htext = $xpath->query('//h2[contains(@class, "make-it-pretty")]')->item(0);
    echo $htext->textContent;
```

Comment: Off of the top of my head: get rid of `->item(0)` and loop through the array contained within `$htext`.

Comment: htext only contains one item I need and I need 2, the link and h2 span text. But I did try it, I got less than I am getting now...lol

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `$doc->loadHTMLFile` instead, but:

```
<?php
$html = '<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>Title Here</title></head>
  <body>
    <h2 class="make-it-pretty"><a class="more-pretty" href="some-file-somewhere"><span class="another-class">Product Name</span></a></h2>
  </body></html>';
$doc = @new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML($html);
function getElementsByClassName($className, $withinNode = null){
  global $doc;
  $d = $withinNode ?? $doc;
  $r = []; $a = $d->getElementsByTagName('*');
  foreach($a as $n){
    if($n->getAttribute('class') === $className)$r[] = $n;
  }
  return $r;
}
$anotherClass = getElementsByClassName('another-class');
// getElementsByClassName('make-it-pretty'); works as well, in this case
echo $anotherClass[0]->textContent;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out about 30 seconds before you posted your answer, mine is very similar so i gave you the upvote! (After I got done my happy dance of course.)

Answer (score 0):

try this without Xpath

```
<?
$html ='<h2 class="make-it-pretty"> <a class="more-pretty" href="some-file-somewhere"> <span class="another-class">Product Name</span> </a> </h2><h2 class="make-it-pretty"> <a class="more-pretty" href="some-file-somewhere"> <span class="another-class">Product Name</span> </a> </h2><h2 class="make-it-pretty"> <a class="more-pretty" href="some-file-somewhere"> <span class="another-class">Product Name</span> </a> </h2>';
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
if($dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOWARNING)){
    $h2s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
    foreach ($h2s as $h2) {
        $as = $h2->getElementsByTagName('a');
        echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($as);
        foreach($as as $a){
            print_r('link :'.$a->getAttribute('href')."\n");
            $spans = $a->getElementsByTagName('span');
        }
        
        foreach($spans as $span){
            print_r('content :'.$span->nodeValue."\n");
            }
        
        
    }
}
```